# What is the popular way to simulate an Ito process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Ito formula is defined as a process of the form

$$
X(t)=X(0)+\int_0^t\delta(s)dW_s +\int_0^t\theta(s)ds
$$

one obvious way to simulate it is to first generate a Brownian motion and then use the Euler method.

But are there better ways?

Comment: If $\delta$ and $\theta$ are $L^2$ deterministic functions of time $X$ is gaussian with mean $\int_0^t\theta(s)d$ variance  $\int_0^t\delta^2(s)ds$  unless mistaken called Wiener integral.

Comment: @TheBridge You need to further compute the covariance in order to determine paths but in the case of deterministic mean and variance this will work out.

Comment: Hi Ian I'm sorry I don't get it, what covariance are your talking about. I assumed Preston was in a 1-dim setting and both integrands are deterministic functions of time.

Comment: @TheBridge If you want to generate paths rather than sampling from a particular time, and you want to do so by just sampling from a random vector directly (which is a good way to do it when the coefficients in the SDE are deterministic) then you need to resolve the correlation between $X_t$ and $X_s$.

Comment: Though I am actually mostly wrong: you can just do the same thing integrating from $s$ to $t$ to get an increment from $s$ to $t$, since the increments are independent.

Comment: Ok I get it but if you want to sample $X$ at an extra time $t_2$ from $t_1$ you only have to sample $X_{t_2} = X_{t_1} +\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \delta(s) dB_s +\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \theta(s) ds$ that is again gaussian with mean ... variance ... and repeat the process

Comment: We agree then but this is a very amenable case, as the notation is a bit ambiguous I just wanted to note this case as it might be of particular interest for Preston Lui  regards